# White flash/flicker during shared element transition between fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, shared-element-transition

I'm using shared element transition between two fragments. The animation works well, but there is a white flash which happens in the fragment.

In my first fragment, I set shared element transition using:

```
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction()
    .addSharedElement(ivPic, ViewCompat.getTransitionName(ivPic))
    .addToBackStack(null)
    .replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
    .commit();
```

And in my second fragment inside `onCreate()`:

```
Transition transition = TransitionInflater.from(getContext()).inflateTransition(R.transition.shared_element_transition);
setSharedElementEnterTransition(transition);
setSharedElementReturnTransition(transition);
```

**Things I've tried:**

- `setEnterTransition(null)` in my second fragment
- `setCustomAnimations(0, 0)` in fragment transition in first fragment

Comment: Hey, ever find a solution?